# what do we mean by variational model?

Tags: optimization, mathematical-modeling

I encountered the term in a paper where the author constrcuted a new model (that he called a variational model): $$\min_{D,W,C}\|Y-DC\|_F^2 + \gamma J(C,W,L)$$ based on a classic one: 
$$\min_{D,C}\|Y-DC\|_F^2 $$

Comment: Are you familiar with LASSO ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon, not really

Comment: I saw your other question, where you did not accept the answer, even though a user answered your question. Look into how this site operates, to get the most out of it.

Comment: @ŽigaSajovic, thanks for notifying, it is done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variational model is one, where we optimize over functions as opposed to over values. Lets take the classic case from your question
$$\min_{D,C}\|Y-DC\|_F^2 $$
in which we optimize over $D$ and $C$, which are (probably) meant to be functions. I say probably, because you did not supply the article you are reading.

You can look into [Euler-Lagrange equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) as an introdution to [variational calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations), that deals with such questions. The classic case is finding the [Brachistochrone curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachistochrone_curve).

Another example of this is the [expectation minimization algorithm](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=363730). In contemporary deep learning, [variational autoencoders](http://kvfrans.com/variational-autoencoders-explained/) work with this idea, where a neural network is used to approximate the function (as opposed to minimizing over the entire function space).

Comment: D is a dictionary to be learned and C represent a matrix of coding vectors, the model presents an optimization problem for sparse coding

Comment: can you provide me an example of what you mean by optimizing over values ?

Comment: For example optimizing a function f$:R \to R$, that takes values as arguments. Lets say $f(x)=x^2$. While over functions means optimizing a functional $L: f \to R$, that takes functions as arguments. Lets say $\int \sqrt{\frac{1+f'(x)^2}{f(x)}}dx$.